# Getting jQuery's scrollLeft to work

Tags: jquery, scroll

Good morning,

I'm having a problem getting something to animate left and right based on the scrollLeft value of its parent.

`.section` is inside `.container`, and as `.container` scrolls off the screen, `.section` should stay on the screen based on the `scrollLeft` value of `.container`.

I've set up a `.show-me` div to show myself what should be being set as the new `left` value of `.section`. It is showing the proper scroll offset, and when I change the `left` value using Inspect Element in Chrome, `.section` moves to the right spot.

But they don't work together. Any clues as to what's going on?

I've tried both of these approaches:

```
$('.container').scroll(function() {
    offset = $(".container").scrollLeft();
    $(".section").css("left",offset+"px !important");
    $(".show-me").text(offset+"px !important");
});
```

and

```
setInterval(function(){
    offset = $(".container").scrollLeft();
    $(".section").css("left",offset+"px !important");
    $(".show-me").text(offset+"px !important");
},1);
```

And neither seem to work for me. Help!

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem. From the looks of it, I believe both of your examples should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

It works when I take the `!important` off the CSS attribute. I'm not sure why this works, but it does.

Thank you for your answer though, Christofer!

Comment: Glad you found the problem! Are you using `!important` within your CSS-file? That is almost never recommended. It breaks the cascading rules of CSS and often causes these kinds of mysterious issues that often are a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: I use it pretty sparingly. I am pulling CSS from at least 3 places for this page (global styles, default theme, current theme), so I need to be on top of the cascading. I only use `!important` in places where I need to override rules in files with later calls by rules in files with earlier calls.

Thanks for the tip though! Before I learned how CSS cascaded, I had more than my share of headaches.

Comment: If you want to, that can be achieved without the use of `!important`. As longs as your earlier rules have a higher specificity than your later rules, they will have precedence no matter the order. Here is [a good article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) on CSS specificity to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be on the first line, your selector `$('container')` is missing a `.` at the beginning. I guess it should be `$('.container')`. You try to apply a scroll-event listener to an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: That was a mistake in transcribing. It's not that way in the code. `.container` has a different name and I renamed it to `.container` here for ease and accessibility. I've updated my code above. The problem still exists.